# How to go to fragment from another fragment in mvp

Tags: android, android-fragments, mvp

First of all i new to mvp design pattern

I have activity with two fragments,

The activity have presenter handle logic with bottom navigation view and search icon on toolbar

The fragments have another presenter to handle their own logic

Now i want to go to a fragment from current fragment

But confused about where to write transaction code

Should it be in current fragment view or in fragment presenter or where!?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In MainPresenter implement the Presenter navigation logic. And in Main activity just navigate the fragments like:

```
    @Override
    public void setFragment(BaseFragment fragment) {
            //ataching to fragment the navigation presenter
            fragment.atachPresenter(presenter);
            //showing the presenter on screen
            getSupportFragmentManager()
                    .beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.fragment_container,fragment)
                    .commit();
        }
```

For more info please follow the link:
   https://medium.com/@urmanschi.mihail/mvp-fragment-navigation-from-inside-fragments-2c4388f97904

Comment: A presenter which implements your Main activity presenter and Fragment navigation presenter.

Comment: have you checked the link? It will give you more clarity.

Comment: ok it worked for me well and i understand the example, but in mvp when i click on button in fragment the logic supposed to be in fragment presenter and in this example when i clicked on button i call interface that implemented in activity presenter, and fragment presenter has no role with that button